# joda-time Given a datetime,get the next occurence of datetime?

Tags: java, jodatime

For a given joda-time for example, `"2018-03-20 08:00:00"` or `"2016-03-20 08:00:00"`, what is the best way get the next occurrence datetime, as `"2019-03-20 08:00:00"`?

My current solution is :

```
if(dt.isBeforNow()){
 dt = dt.plusYear(now.getYear()-dt.getYear());
  if(dt.isBeforNow()){
   dt = dt.plusYear(1);
  }
}
```

Comment: looks good to me

Comment: `dt.plusYear(now.getYear()-dt.getYear());` does not do anything because the `DateTime`-object is immutable so you need to reassign the result.

Comment: thanks, Meno Hchschild, I edit it

Answer (score 0):

I think this way better then your code. But there can be more solutions for this calculations.

```
DateTime prevDate = new DateTime("2016-03-20 08:00:00");
DateTime nowDate = new DateTime("2018-03-20 08:00:00");
int yearDiff = Days.daysBetween(prevDate,nowDate).getYears();
DateTime nextDate = nowDate.plusYears(yearDiff);
```